# How i can include static library NTL in new project?

Tags: c++, ntl

When I build my program, I have next error:

Error   C1083
Cannot open include file: 'ZZ.h': No such file or directory NTL
C:\Progs\NTL\src.cpp

My code:

```
#include <ZZ.h>
     
int main(){
    ZZ a, b, c;
    return 0;
}
```

1. Download library ntl 11.5.1 for Windows from https://libntl.org/download.html
2. Build static library

   1. File \ New \ Project Existing Code...
   2. Next
   3. Project file location: C:\2\WinNTL-11_5_1\src
   4. Preject name: ntl
   5. Next
   6. Project type: Static library (LIB) project
   7. Finish
   8. Project \ Properties \ VC++ Directories \ Include Directories \ Edit: C:\2\WinNTL-11_5_1\include
   9. Build \ Rebuild Solution
3. Copy static library _NTL.lib in my project NTL
4. In NTL project:

   1. Project \ Properties \ VC++ Directories \ Library Directories -> ./NTL
   2. Project \ Properties \ Linker \ Input \ Additional Dependencies -> _NTL.lib

Answer (score 0):

All of the [NTL header files](https://github.com/libntl/ntl/tree/main/include/NTL) are in a directory called `NTL`. You need to reflect this in your `#include` directive.

```
#include <NTL/ZZ.h>
```

Comment: I did it. Don’t work.